# How to control cell overlap in mosaic dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

I am trying to set the cell overlap values to maximum in a mosaic dataset.  I have unsuccessfully set the mosaic dataset properties to the following with a blend width of 500:

```
Properties > Defaults > Default Mosaic Operator > Max
```

The mosaic does not change at all when I set these parameters (see screenshot).  The Mosaic to New Raster tool with the MAX cell overlap rule seems to work well with removing the tile edge effects.  Where am I going wrong here--how can I make sure that the mosaic dataset uses a maximum rule for cell overlap areas?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the seamline method? The docs http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000024m000000 say *You will want to set Blend when using the Seamline mosaic method.* nice of them to decide that for you.. if so, perhaps remove the seamlines and try *by attribute* as your mosaic operator.